# How to seek a textfile?

Tags: pascal, lazarus

I am using a textfile to store some data so that I can use it later to create reports, but the data I stored is in multiple lines ie.

```
1
1
2
2
```

Lets say if I want to read data from number 2, how would I be able assign a variable to the third and fourth line without the 1's (the numbers will not be the same in the actual data). Seek() will not work since it is a textfile and I won't be able to use writeln() if I changed the type. Is there anyway I can do this without using records?

Edit: There will be exactly 96 lines and all lines may not have the same number of digits.

Comment: Are all the lines the same length? Is the file encoding a fixed length encoding?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to these stuff and so I don't understand the second question, hope my edit answers some of it.

Comment: You can learn about fixed length text encodings by searching. This might require you to spend some time reading about the topic. Even if the encoding is fixed length, if the line lengths cannot be predicted, how can you expect to have random access. How can you predict where line 50 starts, for instance, without knowing the lengths of all preceeding lines? It will really help you if you learn about how files are represented on disk, and what information is present.

Comment: Have you considered using `readln`?

Answer (score 2):

Since the input file is small you could use `TStringList` to process it. Here's an example.

First few records of a sample text file called adrian.txt containing random numbers.

```
15
37
46
29
33
37
37
50
41
48
3
9
31
50
```

Lazarus code: The `TStringList` object `s` uses its `LoadFromFile` method to load the contents of the text file into itself. Now the contents of the individual records are available, indexed by their numbers. Only note that these numbers are zero-relative; ie, the first record become the 0th string in `TStringList`.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: TStringList;
begin
  s := TStringList.Create;
  s.LoadFromFile('adrian.txt');
  Memo1.Lines.Add(s[0]);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(s[1]);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(s[2])
end;
```

Press the button and this is what you see.

[image]